# Are positional notation systems for natural numbers wreath products of semigroups?

Tags: group-theory, number-systems, semigroups, natural-numbers, wreath-product

Suppose we are given the finite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ and the monoid of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, both of which are semigroups. Does the restricted wreath product $(\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}) \wr \mathbb{N}$ define the base-$b$ positional notation system for natural numbers?

Comment: I don't think that would deal correctly with carrying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the wreath product does not implement carrying as necessary for a positional notation system. It would instead define an group structure isomorphic to the polynomial ring over the ring of integers modulo $b$.